# Discord music bot plays song if someone in another server plays somthing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote a basic discord music bot in python. It works great besides when I want to use it in multiple servers. When I have the music bot in one server playing something. If someone else in a different server plays something it changes the song I am listening to, to the song that the other person queued. I am guessing this is an instancing issue. But how do I make it different per server kind of like rythm?

Comment: Store the current song source in a dictionary with the server id as the key. There's lots of music bot examples out there, have a quick look around.

Comment: @stijndcl Ok thanks, Im guessing there is a way to use client.play per server?

Comment: If you mean [`VoiceClient.play`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.play), then yes, since you can get a `VoiceClient` instance for each voice channel that the bot has joined.

Comment: @Benjin thanks I for some reason didn't realize that you could create multiple instances of a VoiceClient.